# Disappearing Opportunity Products

Tags: apex, trigger, visual-workflow, opportunity-lineitem

We have an issue that opportunity products are deleted by some kind of process / apex whatever.
What would be the best way to debug this?
We tried delta checking with the backup system tried to log user actions but so far we could not work it out.

Is there any way to e.g. write the context of the delete to some kind of log-Object in Salesforce. **I'm thinking about a** **flow or trigger that is triggering on the delete and then writing the current context to some kind of log object**. So we can at least see WHAT is causing those deletes.

Is this possible in flow or Apex?

Edit: Added more tags.

Comment: Flip Debug logs on with enough granularity, it might catch it. For explicit logging via Apex or flow, we recommend   [Nebula](https://github.com/jongpie/NebulaLogger)

Answer (score 0):

First, I would query for these deleted records to see when they get deleted. Use queryAll and filter for `isDeleted = true`. Look at the created date and last modified date to see if it happens immediately or after some time period. If immediately, then it is likely a trigger or flow - look at your triggers for OpportunityProduct and Opportunity. If there is some delay, look at the last modified by user to see who is doing it. If it is some integration user, then it might be from off platform. If it is always the created by user, then look for some sort trigger or flow that might be kicking off a scheduled job.

If you are still unable to find it, you could perhaps add a beforeDelete trigger to OpportunityLineItem that logs things like the [Quiddity](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_enum_System_Quiddity.htm).

Comment: Records get deleted randomly after a couple of days. Random user as it seems. As far as I know Opportunity Products are not soft deleted and can't be found with that query.
Triggers are clean.
Has to be somewhere in the platform (LWC or Apex) Any ideas how I could get pieces of the context while triggering on the delete?

Comment: I just tested and I can queryAll OpportunityLineItem where isDeleted=true.